# Missing information_schema_stats_expiry in MariaDB server system variables

Tags: mariadb, auto-increment

Using the Server version: 10.3.38-MariaDB - MariaDB Server.

Running the command

```
SET SESSION information_schema_stats_expiry=0;
```

always results in this error:

```
#1193 - Unknown system variable 'information_schema_stats_expiry'
```

The same works fine on MySQL 8.0.32 !

The reason why we want to run this command each time a new request is received to our server is because of this: It connects to the database via the PHP MySQLi, and the first command is to set **information_schema_stats_expiry** to zero. This is because we need to make sure that some possible subsequent DB queries may want to get the latest 'Auto_increment' value for certain DB tables, and not retrieve this value from a possibly old cache.

We use something like this to get the 'Auto_increment' value:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `<DB-name>` WHERE `name` LIKE '<table-name>';
```

And sometimes change the 'Auto_increment' as well:

```
ALTER TABLE `<table-name>` AUTO_INCREMENT = <new-value>;
```

Is there something equivalent in MariaDB to what MySQL has for the '**information_schema_stats_expiry**'?
See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_information_schema_stats_expiry ?

Or does the MariaDB server already already retrieve the latest current non-cached 'Auto_increment' value anyway?

JNeuhoff